# How do I create a second Angular App inside Angular project, in ABP.IO and make IdentityServer work?

Tags: angular, abp

**ABP Framework version**: v4.3.0

**User Interface**: Angular v11.2.11

**Database provider**: EF Core

How do I create a second Angular App inside Angular project, in a way that allows me to consume the same C# proxy, and also use the same IdentityServer?

**What I've tried so far**:

- Made the second app via angular command `ng generate application exampleApp` and started moving dependencies from ABP Angular project app.module.
- The second app runs on port `4300` so `http://localhost:4300` was added to `CorsOrigins` in `appsettings`
- Under appsettings in DbMigrator project and under IdentityServer:Clients added the following:

```
"exampleApp": {
    "ClientId": "exampleApp",
    "ClientSecret": "1q2w3e*",
    "RootUrl": "http://localhost:4300"
}
```

- In the exampleApp environment.ts the following was added:

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4300';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  application: {
    baseUrl,
    name: 'exampleApp',
    logoUrl: '',
  },
  oAuthConfig: {
    issuer: 'https://localhost:44350', 
    redirectUri: baseUrl,
    clientId: 'exampleApp',
    responseType: 'code',
    scope: 'offline_access exampleApp'
  },
  apis: {
    default: {
      url: 'https://localhost:44350',
      rootNamespace: 'AB.XYZ',
    },
  },
} as Environment;
```

When I serve exampleApp on port `4300` then try to login it redirects me to the primary app on port `4200`.

Could you please provide me with guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Update Database Seeding

You need to create a new identityserver client. Best way to do it is updating [IdentityServerDataSeedContributor](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/4a000bcf774a5fff693129f761f932326ba90f32/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain/IdentityServer/IdentityServerDataSeedContributor.cs#L167-L183) as below:

```cs
var mySecondAngularApp = configurationSection["MySecondAngularApp:ClientId"];
        if (!mySecondAngularApp .IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            var mySecondAngularAppClientRootUrl = configurationSection["MySecondAngularApp:RootUrl"]?.TrimEnd('/');

            await CreateClientAsync(
                name: mySecondAngularApp,
                scopes: commonScopes,
                grantTypes: new[] { "password", "client_credentials", "authorization_code" },
                secret: (configurationSection["MySecondAngularApp:ClientSecret"] ?? "1q2w3e*").Sha256(),
                requireClientSecret: false,
                redirectUri: mySecondAngularAppClientRootUrl,
                postLogoutRedirectUri: mySecondAngularAppClientRootUrl,
                corsOrigins: new[] { mySecondAngularAppClientRootUrl.RemovePostFix("/") }
            );
        }
```

To get the related configuration, update end seeder application [DbMigrator appsettings.json](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.DbMigrator/appsettings.json):

```json
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyProjectName_App": {
        "ClientId": "MyProjectName_App",
        "ClientSecret": "1q2w3e*",
        "RootUrl": "http://localhost:4200"
      },
      "MySecondAngularApp": {
        "ClientId": "MySecondAngularApp",
        "ClientSecret": "1q2w3e*",
        "RootUrl": "https://localhost:4300"
      },
  }
```

Seed the database.

#### 2. Update IdentityServer

Add CORS and otherAngularUrl to [IdentityServer appsettings](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.IdentityServer/appsettings.json):

```json
{
  "App": {
    "SelfUrl": "https://localhost:44301",
    "ClientUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
    "OtherAngularUrl": "http://localhost:4300",
    "CorsOrigins": "https://*.MyProjectName.com,http://localhost:4200,http://localhost:4300,https://localhost:44307,https://localhost:44300",
    "RedirectAllowedUrls": "http://localhost:4200,ttp://localhost:4300,https://localhost:44307"
  },
...
```

Update [IdentityServerModule](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.IdentityServer/MyProjectNameIdentityServerModule.cs#L123-L124):

```cs
Configure<AppUrlOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Applications["MVC"].RootUrl = configuration["App:SelfUrl"];
    options.RedirectAllowedUrls.AddRange(configuration["App:RedirectAllowedUrls"].Split(','));

    options.Applications["Angular"].RootUrl = configuration["App:ClientUrl"];
    options.Applications["Angular"].Urls[AccountUrlNames.PasswordReset] = "account/reset-password";

    options.Applications["OtherAngular"].RootUrl = configuration["App:OtherAngularUrl"];
    options.Applications["OtherAngular"].Urls[AccountUrlNames.PasswordReset] = "account/reset-password";
});
```